# Get All Default Error Info on Custom Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

How would I be able to capture all the information from the default error page onto a custom error page. I am currently able to get the stack trace but I really want the description and exception details.

I am currently getting the stack trace by doing the following

```
HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
Exception exception = ctx.Server.GetLastError();
exception.StackTrace.ToString()
```

But i really want to get the exception details. (below is the default page i recieve)

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The TargetControlID of 'mp1' is not valid. A control with ID 'btnShow' could not be found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The TargetControlID of 'mp1' is not valid. A control with ID 'btnShow' could not be found.

Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 
[InvalidOperationException: The TargetControlID of 'mp1' is not valid. A control with ID 'btnShow' could not be found.]
   System.Web.UI.ExtenderControl.RegisterWithScriptManager() +356
   System.Web.UI.ExtenderControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +20
   AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +64
   AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +188
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +88
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +883
```

Comment: Use Application_Error() Event from Global.asax file to capture the error

Comment: What i am using that method in the global.asax file. what functions do i use? i am using exception.stacktrace to get the stack trace but i a not figuring out how to get the exception details.